# SF4 JMSSerializer with annotation returns empty data

Tags: json, jmsserializerbundle, symfony4

I use JMSSerializerBundle and FOSRestBundle in my Symfony4 project, I don't use yml metadata but annotations. This is one of my entity:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PageRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="page")
 * @Serializer\AccessType("public_method")
 */
class Page
```

And my FOSRest configs:

```
fos_rest:
    body_listener: true
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
    service:
        view_handler: tigris_base.view_handler
    view:
        default_engine: twig
        view_response_listener: force
        formats:
            json: true
            pdf: true
            xls: true
            html: false
            xml: true
        templating_formats:
            pdf: false
            xls: false
            json: false
            html: true
            xml: false
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: html
        prefix_methods: false
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    allowed_methods_listener: true
```

I have one entity in my database but the json response is empty. Is it possible that JMS cannot serialize my entity?

Comment: No one is able to answer your question, please add more details, please read stack guide to asking.

Comment: Ok I found the problem: my entities is an iterator from Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator object, I must to call "getArrayCopy" method to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem: my entities is an iterator from Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator object, I must to call "getArrayCopy" method to serialize.